# Writing good tests using mock module in unittest python

Tags: python, unit-testing, input, return-value, patch

I need to write some test cases for my method:

```
def checking_input_main_menu():
while True:
    option = input('Enter an option: ').strip()
    if option.isdigit() and int(option) in [1, 2]:
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid option. Enter option 1 or 2:')
        continue
return int(option)
```

I already knew how to write some simple cases for valid inputs (1 and 2). However, I spent a ton of time writing invalid test codes, but they did not work as I expected.

```
 @patch('builtins.input', return_value = '12')
def test_invalid_input_menu_2(self, mock_inputs):
    self.assertFalse(checking_input_main_menu(), 'Invalid option. Enter '
                                                 'option 1 or 2')
```

When running the test, the program went into an infinite loop ('Invalid option. Enter option 1 or 2:'). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the test, the problem is your `checking_input_main_menu` is an infinite loop if `12` is given as an input

Comment: You may want to use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=side_effect#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) instead of setting `return_value`. This way you can provide more than one input value, including a valid one. That would test that you can input invalid values, and the return value will be the first valid one.